# Best practice of parsing RESTful WebService response with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jakarta-ee, rest

I'm developing a JAX-RS application and it's working fine. Now, I want to develop a web service client application using Rails. And my question is which is the best way to parse a RESTful webservice's response in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the service is returning. I'd say that you could use a variety of gems to do it. Lately I've been using [HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to get and parse automatically the response of a call to a RESTful API.

Once I get all the data I then map it to a model so that's it's easier to manipulate later on. The way you'll do this mapping will really depend on the type on response you'll get.